# Alert Dialog not Showing . Only a Blank white page is coming

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Folks,

I have created a dialog fragment which will show a Dialog with Ringtone . But, Ringtone is playing and a White Blank page is coming .

Please guide me where I am growing wrong .

AlarmDialog.java

```
public class AlarmDialogPopUp extends Activity {

    Ringtone ringtone;
    Long rowId;Constants.TableTypes fragType;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Activity activity = this;

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        rowId = intent.getExtras().getLong(DatabaseHandler1.KEY_ID);
        fragType = (Constants.TableTypes) intent.getExtras().get(DatabaseHandler1.fragmentidenifier);


        // Get the alarm ID from the intent extra data

        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(AlarmDialogPopUp.this, uri);
        ringtone.play();

         }
        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog ( int id)
        {
            super.onCreateDialog(id);

            // Build the dialog
            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            alert.setTitle("ALARM REMINDER");
            alert.setMessage("Check Your Reminder");
            alert.setCancelable(false);

            alert.setPositiveButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    ringtone.stop();
                    // Constants.TableTypes fragType = (Constants.TableTypes) intent.getExtras().get(DatabaseHandler1.fragmentidenifier)

                    Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmDialogPopUp.this, PostClickNotificationActivity.class);
                    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
                    //getApplicationContext().startActivity(notificationIntent);
                    intent.putExtra(DatabaseHandler1.KEY_ID, rowId);
                    intent.putExtra(DatabaseHandler1.fragmentidenifier, fragType);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    AlarmDialogPopUp.this.finish();

                }


            });

            // Create and return the dialog
            AlertDialog dlg = alert.create();
            //dlg.show();
            dlg.show();
            return dlg;
        }
    }
```

I have tried create method, show() everything as mentioned in other posts . But, Its not working . It rings and a blank page comes .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display your dialog in your onCreate method like this

```
public class AlarmDialogPopUp extends Activity {

    Ringtone ringtone;
    Long rowId;Constants.TableTypes fragType;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Activity activity = this;

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        rowId = intent.getExtras().getLong(DatabaseHandler1.KEY_ID);
        fragType = (Constants.TableTypes) intent.getExtras().get(DatabaseHandler1.fragmentidenifier);


        // Get the alarm ID from the intent extra data

        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(AlarmDialogPopUp.this, uri);
        ringtone.play();
         displayDialog();
         }

        public void displayDialog()
        {

            // Build the dialog
            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlarmDialogPopUp.this);

            alert.setTitle("ALARM REMINDER");
            alert.setMessage("Check Your Reminder");
            alert.setCancelable(false);

            alert.setPositiveButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    ringtone.stop();
                    // Constants.TableTypes fragType = (Constants.TableTypes) intent.getExtras().get(DatabaseHandler1.fragmentidenifier)

                    Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmDialogPopUp.this, PostClickNotificationActivity.class);
                    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
                    //getApplicationContext().startActivity(notificationIntent);
                    intent.putExtra(DatabaseHandler1.KEY_ID, rowId);
                    intent.putExtra(DatabaseHandler1.fragmentidenifier, fragType);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    finish();

                }


            });

            alert.show();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`dlg.show();` ...That´s wrong. Usually you are calling `showDialog(int)` method of an activity. But this is deprecated, you should create your own Dialog, or use `DialogFragment`

remove `dlg.show()` inside `onCreateDialog()` and call for example `showDialog(0)` in `onCreate()`.

[Using DialogFragment](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html)

[example of custom dialog](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

Comment: Thanks a lot . I got it .